# .htaccess Disable cache-control mod_expires and mod_headers for paths that do not have physical directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, cache-control

I have Laravel application that is using mod_expires, mod_headers, and mod_gzip in the public folder to enable caching on the frontend of the site.  However, in the admin panel this is breaking some of the functionality.

I would like to disable/exclude the paths to the admin panel which are generated using mod_rewrite.  I would have just put a .htaccess file in a folder with the same name as path, but this causes issues as well.

The path to the admin panel would be "/manage".

Here's what the .htaccess file looks like at this time.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>    

    RewriteEngine On    

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]    

    # Secure Front Themes...
    RewriteRule ^themes/.*\.(blade.php|php)$ - [F,L,NC]    

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
    </IfModule>    

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
        </FilesMatch>
        <FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
        </FilesMatch>

        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </IfModule>    

    <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
        mod_gzip_on Yes
        mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
        mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
        mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
        mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
        mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
        mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
        mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
    </ifModule>
```

Thanks in advance